# iPhone microphones, are they worth looking at

Tags: microphone, field-recording, recording, equipment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this the Zoom killer?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/11525/is-this-the-zoom-killer)

Hallo All

I often find myself in a situation where I can hear a brilliant sound (when shopping, for example, or trawelling to work) but I do not have the recording gear with me. I always have my iPhone, though. Could this microphone be the answer? Can it be used for recording in situations where using professional mic is out of the question? Or would that be a waste of time and money (although it is quite cheap) Can it produce at least semi-pro quality of sound? Has any one ever used it?
http://www.gear4music.com/Recording-and-Computers/Tascam-iM2-Stereo-Condenser-Microphone-for-iPhone-iPad/I4N
Or maybe there are other, better solutions?

Thank You
AlicjaS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/11525/is-this-the-zoom-killer), where this has already been discussed.

Comment: Oh, how could I have missed that! Thank You